# MSSQL Bulk Insert CSV - Multiple columns include commas

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, csv, bulkinsert, bcp

I'm running MSSQL Server Management Studio R2 and I have a large .csv file with ~30 columns and ~10,000,000 rows. I downloaded the data from an internet source in about 900 separate files and concatenated them to a single file with a .cmd script, so now I have a full file ready for insertion into the database.

Unfortunately, large numbers in multiple columns are recorded as strings that contain internal commas (i.e., `"50,000,000"` or `"3,972,721"`). Note that the double quotes *are* included in the file formatting. `BULK INSERT` considers these commas to be text field delimiters rather than part of the string.

This is my insert statement.

```
BULK INSERT Database.dbo.table
    FROM '\\server\filepath\file.csv'
    WITH
        (
            FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
            ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
        );
```

In the table I created to hold the data, the rows in question have the `varchar(max)` data type, as anything else I've tried throws an error.

The incorrect output for `"3,972,721"` currently bleeds over into extra rows, completely distorting the rest of the table.

```
ROW1        ROW2        ROW3
"3          972         721"
```

I would like the correct output for `"3,972,721"` to  be

```
ROW1
3972721
```

I'm looking either for a way to force the `BULK INSERT` command to cast these strings as ints (with the added constraint that some of the datapoint strings include a `+` symbol, for example `"2,500,000,000+"`), or another method of insertion entirely, such as bcp.

Thank you!

Comment: I know with SSIS you can specify that the double-quotations are field delimiters.

Comment: I could not find any way to overcome this using bulk insert, but SSIS allows you to specify a text qualifier. [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23289514/comma-within-fields-in-csv-file-import-to-db-using-ssis)

Comment: OK thanks. Looks like I'll go about it using SSIS.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a text qualifier with bulk inserts by using a format file. This related StackOverflow question has pretty good documentation on how to do this:

[Bulk insert with text qualifier in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25726385/bulk-insert-with-text-qualifier-in-sql-server)